# Date of birth fields

Tags: localisation

We're trying to have the date-of-birth field for our contacts displayed in dd-mm-yyyy format when using mailings but despite me altering every single relevant setting in Civi...our test mailings still display the date of birth in yyyy-mm-dd format? Why might this be?

Comment: It would help if you could state what version of CiviCRM you are using with what CMS?

Comment: Civi 4.6. With Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

It might well be that the relevant function does (wrongly) not use the date formatting based on the settings. Could you check that?

Comment: Well we're using CiviMail for these mailings but that function doesn't appear to have a separate date formatting setting.

Comment: I am sure it does not :-) I meant if you have any PHP skills and would be able to check in the code?